# Why does the ondrej ppa to install php7 also installs php5?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, php5, upgrade, php7

I'm installing php7 on Ubuntu 14.04 using ppa:ondrej/php and I realised it also installs php5. Is there a reason for that? Should I remove php5 if I'm not going to use it? What's the good practice?

Thank you.

Comment: can you clear the question

Comment: I think it was clear, no @SukhjinderSingh? I'm installing php7 in an Ubuntu 14.04 using the ppa:ondrej/php which I noticed also installs php5. Should I delete the php5 version and keep only the php7 ?

Comment: My question is also why the ppa installs php5. Maybe there's a reason for that and I didn't get it.